# iReport - XY Chart: Disable connection defined through x-value

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I have a subdataset for a chart in my report that looks like:

```
+------+---+----+
| name | x | y  |
+------+---+----+
| a    | 0 | 9  |
+------+---+----+
| b    | 1 | 13 |
+------+---+----+
| c    | 2 | 20 |
+------+---+----+
| d    | 3 | 22 |
+------+---+----+
| e    | 4 | 23 |
+------+---+----+
| f    | 4 | 24 |
+------+---+----+
| g    | 3 | 17 |
+------+---+----+
| h    | 2 | 14 |
+------+---+----+
| i    | 1 | 10 |
+------+---+----+
| j    | 0 | 3  |
+------+---+----+
```

This creates me a chart that looks like: `a-j-b-i-c-h-d-g-e-f` (ordered by x value)

But I want that my chart is ordered by the table `a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j`

[image: graph]

How can I do that with iReport?

Comment: If SQL, could you provide the SELECT? Also, you might consider using Jaspersoft Studio.

Comment: @tobi6 The SQL query is like `DATA FROM a-e UNION ALL DATA FROM f-j`. It is not possible to switch the program...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

You have to add the attribute **autoSort** to your **xySeries** in the XML code

```
<xyDataset>
    <dataset .../>
    <xySeries autoSort="false">
    ...
    </xySeries>
</xyDataset>
```

(Found the solution [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/5713))